# How to draw line animation using ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, animation

Basically, I want to create a movable, horizontal line, whose coordinates are (-4, h(t)) and (4, h(t)), that will move along the y-axis as t increases. Now, I already knew how to draw a movable dot:

```
MovieFrames = 
  Table[
    ListPlot[{{0, h[k / 10]}}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0, 75}}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
    {k, 0, 41}];

ListAnimate[MovieFrames, 
  AnimationRunning -> false, AnimationRepetitions -> 10, Animation -> Rate]
```

The above instructions will draw a movable dot that moves along the y-axis as t increases. I think the instruction for drawing a line is just like the extension to the above instruction, but I tried Graphics[Line..] and LisPlot, both of which did not work. Could someone give me a sample instruction for how to create a movable, horizontal line? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question. This way, people are more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: I will do that next time. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the definition for `h[t]` so I will use

```
h[t_] = 10 t;
```

To make a line with `ListPlot` you need two points and the option `Joined->True`

```
MovieFrames =
  Table[
   ListPlot[
    {{-4, h[k/10]}, {4, h[k/10]}},
    Joined -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 75}},
    PlotStyle -> Red],
   {k, 0, 41}];
```

or use `ListLinePlot` and the points are automatically joined

```
MovieFrames =
  Table[
   ListLinePlot[
    {{-4, h[k/10]}, {4, h[k/10]}},
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 75}},
    PlotStyle -> Red],
   {k, 0, 41}];
```

or use `ParametricPlot`

```
MovieFrames =
  Table[
   ParametricPlot[{t, h[k/10]}, {t, -4, 4},
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 75}},
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],
   {k, 0, 41}];
```

or just `Plot`

```
MovieFrames =
  Table[
   Plot[h[k/10], {t, -4, 4},
    PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 75}},
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio],
   {k, 0, 41}];

ListAnimate[MovieFrames, AnimationRunning -> False, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 10, AnimationRate -> 4]
```

[image]

Comment: Got it. Thank you all so much!